# Swing Dialog Layout: run method or constructor?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

When I initiate my Swing dialog layout does it make a difference whether I do it in the class's run method:

```
    public void run()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        ...
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
```

or the class constructor?

```
    public MyClass
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        ...
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
    public void run()
    {
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes it does matter, and the reason is that you should call most Swing code, including creation of your JFrame, on the Swing event thread (the Event Dispatch Thread or EDT). To do this, you usually create your Swing GUI in a Runnable, and queue the Runnable on the event thread by calling something like:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
  public void run() {
     // create your Swing GUI here
     frame = new JFrame();
     ...
     frame.setVisible( true );
  }
});
```

The exceptions are Swing method calls that are documented in the API to be thread-safe such as the `repaint()` method of Components.

Answer (score 3):

This is contextual. As @hovercraftfullofeels points out, you need to make sure ALL your UI code is executed in the `EDT`, including initalisation.

If you're already running in the `EDT`, then there shouldn't be any need to use `InvokeLater` (unless you really want to), otherwise you MUST resync the call back to the `EDT`.

Best to check with `EventQueue.isDispatchingThread`